# FFMPEG: Amplify one channel of audio file

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3, stereo

Okay, so I have one audio file that's in .mp3 and need to amplify only left channel. I have found out how to do i on the whole file using this command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -af "volume=1.5" output.wav
```

But can't find how to do it on only left channel while keeping the right one intact. Can someone help me? I tried looking into `-map` option but couldn't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm gonna get called out by the FFMPEG gurus but here is how I would do it :

- split the stereo .wav into two mono files -left.

  `ffmpeg -i stereo.wav -map_channel 0.0.0 left.wav -map_channel 0.0.1 right.wav`
- amplifly left.wav

  `ffmpeg -i left.wav -af "volume=1.5" left.wav`
- join the mono files back together

  `ffmpeg -i left.wav -i right.wav -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[aout]" -map "[aout]" output.mka`

More info here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation

Answer (score 3):

One simple method using [channelsplit](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#channelsplit), [volume](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#volume), and [amerge](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge):

```
ffmpeg -i stereo.wav -filter_complex "channelsplit[lpre][r];[lpre]volume=1.5[l];[l][r]amerge" output.wav
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to amplify on playback only and found that this worked:

```
ffplay.exe -hide_banner -af "pan=stereo|c0=8*c0|c1=c1" .\recording.webm
```

I also found this worked with `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg.exe -hide_banner -i .\recording.webm -af "pan=stereo|c0=8*c0|c1=c1" transcoded.avi
```